# Google AppEngine PHP Failed to connect to MySQL

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a PHP app running on Google Cloud AppEngine.
Somehow the PHP is throwing this error:

"Failed to connect to MySQL: Unable to find the socket transport "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"

Here is my code:

config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_USERNAME', 'my_username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_password');
define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/<my instance name>');
define('DB_NAME', 'my_db_name');
?>
```

DbConnect.php

```
<?php
class DbConnect
{
    private $conn;
    function __construct()
    {
    }
    function connect()
    {
        require_once 'config.php';
        // Connecting to mysql database
        $this->conn = new mysqli(null, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, 0, DB_HOST);
        // Check for database connection error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        // returing connection resource
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

When I run my php that uses this connect file, the above error gets thrown.

Does anyone know what might I be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Removing the ":" on this line solved it.

```
define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/<my instance name>');
```

to

```
define('DB_HOST', '/cloudsql/<my instance name>');
```